# BeautifulSoup Python is stripping my HTML comments

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My problem is that I want to leave my HTML comments intact but they are stripped.

```
content = """
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Foo</title>
            <!-- testcomment -->
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mycontent">Here's my content</div>
            <!-- testcomment2 -->
        </body>
    </html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, builder=HTMLParserTreeBuilder())
print soup.body.contents
```

returns

```
[u'\n', <div id="mycontent">Here's my content</div>, u'\n', u' testcomment2 ', u'\n']
```

Is there a flag I can pass to have my comments intact?

**EDIT**
The expected output is exaclty what's in the `content` variable.

Comment: @AshokaLella, that is not a duplicate

Comment: It's BeautifulSoup 4

Comment: Please notice my edit I made a mistake - it strips only the <!-- --> tags and leaves the comment content

Comment: Your 'returns' doesn't match what is actually returned. The `str` version of the comment object is just not including the `<!--` and `-->` parts in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are there, but their `__repr__` representation doesn't include the `<!--` and `-->` prefix and postfixes.

You can call the `Comment.output_ready()` method to include those:

```
>>> soup.body.contents[3].output_ready()
u'<!-- testcomment2 -->'
```

or convert a parent to unicode, or call the `.prettify()` method:

```
>>> unicode(soup.body)
u'<body>\n<div id="mycontent">Here\'s my content</div>\n<!-- testcomment2 -->\n</body>'
>>> print(unicode(soup.body))
<body>
<div id="mycontent">Here's my content</div>
<!-- testcomment2 -->
</body>
>>> print(soup.body.prettify())
<body>
 <div id="mycontent">
  Here's my content
 </div>
 <!-- testcomment2 -->
</body>
```

Also see the [*Output formatters* documenation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But unicoding and `prettify()` are not helping . The `output_ready()` works on comments.

Comment: @McAbra: I documented all your options; you did not specify what your expected output was. For *just* the comment object `output_ready` is your best option; the object otherwise gives you just the content of the comment; what most people want from it.

Comment: Ok ty. The expected output is exactly what's in the `content` variable. `prettify()` doesn't even get the comment element :| whats weird because of: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#comments-and-other-special-strings

Comment: @McAbra: In my answer I included a demo of `prettify()` as well; it doesn't work directly on the `Comment` object though.

Comment: @McAbra: `contents` is a *list*, it contains the `Comment` object. The `repr()` output of a `Comment` object is to show *just* the contents of the comment. It is not a string object there (the BeautifulSoup `__repr__` values are not being helpful by making it look like one). As such there is no point in trying to make it print the comment with the prefix and postfix included. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have to make a proxy to a WordPress site (ugh) and wrap it's contents with the header and footer of my site. The WP site has IE comments `<!-- if IE` I need them on my wrapped page.

Comment: You were right. Thank you and I apologize - I had my BS4 lib messed up. Comments were not even in the `contents`. Everthing is fine now. Thanks again.